# Laravel – Calling API connections

Tags: php, api, laravel, model-view-controller

**Repeated Calls** – Lets say you need your Application to talk to an API and you're using guzzle or a wrapper or whatever. I find myself having to call the connection in every controller function e.g:

```
class ExampleController extends Controller
{

    public function one()
    {

      $client = new Client();
      $response = $client->get('http://', 
      [ 'query'  => [ 'secret' => env('SECRET')]]);

      $json = json_decode($response->getBody());
      $data =  $json->object;

      // do stuff
    }

    public function two()
    {
      $client = new Client();
      $response = $client->get('http://', 
      [ 'query'  => [ 'secret' =>  env('SECRET')]]);

      $json = json_decode($response->getBody());
      $data =  $json->object;

      // do stuff
    }
}
```

How do I better handle this? Do I use a service Provider? if so, how would I best implement these calls? Should I create another controller and call all my API connections in each function and then include that controller and call upon each function as required? Should I place it in a `__construct?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lets try the **Dependency inversion principle**

Ok this might sound a bit hard at first and my code might have some typos or minor mistakes but try this

You need to create the interface

```
namespace app\puttherightnamespace; // this deppends on you

interface ExempleRepositoryInterface 
{
    public function getquery(); // if you passinga  variable -> public function getquery('variable1');

}
```

Now you have to create the repo

```
class ExempleRepository implements ExempleRepositoryInterface {

 public function getquery() {

  $client = new Client();
  $response = $client->get('http://', 
  [ 'query'  => [ 'secret' => env('SECRET')]]);

  $json = json_decode($response->getBody());

   return $json->object;
}
```

Now last step is to bind the interface to the repo in a service provider register method

```
public function register()
 {
   $this->app->bind('namespacehere\ExempleRepositoryInterface', 'namespacehere\ExempleRepository');
  }
```

Now everytime you need the result in a controller all you have to do is to ineject

```
class ExempleController extends Controller {
        private $exemple;
        public function __construct(ExempleRepositoryInterface $home) {
            $this->exemple = $exemple;
        }
        public function test() {
            $data = $this->exemple->getquery(); / you can pass a variable here if you want like this $this->exemple->getquery('variable');

            // do stuff
        }
```

this is not the simplest way but this is the best way i guess

Comment: Thank you so much! This helps me a lot. Couple of questions, Where would I put interface and repo in laravel directories? (in /controllers?) with the service provider, would I add this to my AppServiceProvider file?

Comment: No , create another folder inside app folder (or outside of it ) and put the repos there, yea , or you can add that to ur app service provider or create anew service provider (btw you will have to edit composer.json to autoload the new folder to get things working)